# How to Work on VoIP?

Tags: android, streaming, audio-streaming, voip

I want to develop an app in android through which I can easily transfer Voice over Internet (VoIP). There are many application in market like [CSIPSIMPLE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.csipsimple). Is there any tutorial which can start from beginning and also how to maintain its server. What are the basic terminologies which we have to use. Please suggest.

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html

Android has a simple sip stack included which should satisfy your needs. Apps like CSipSimple (most of them) use their own sip stack with different codecs/filters applied to the device's input/output, but that requires more work as these are native due to performance.

So for a simple VoIP application, feel free to use android's utilities. Server software choice and maintenance is depending on what you want to achieve, just google for sip servers and read.

Comment: What about SIP Server and how to maintain that.

Comment: You will have to read for yourself and learn how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

CSipSimple is [open source](https://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/). Just start there. Note that it is GPL, so you won't just be able to copy and use it in a commercial application, but you'll see what's involved internally.

For the server, [Asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org/) has been around for over a decade. There are other alternatives, but Asterisk is the de-facto standard for open source PBX.